# Social Sharing for a third party JQuery widget

Tags: jquery, facebook, api, twitter

I am writing a third party JQuery widget. I wanted to have a Social Sharing option for these widgets. These widgets would be installed for different websites, so the sharing urls, content etc would be specific to that website.

I was starting to write my own code for social sharing, but I wanted to know if there are good API's that already take care of this, which could prevent me from writing my own?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For strictly "Social Sharing" of Twitter and Facebook, you don't need a back-end.  It can all be done client side in a pure jQuery widget.

Answer (score 0):

I use social-share-button. It's implemented in Rails, should be a good start if you're looking to call it in jQUery

https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button

Comment: My backend is not Rails but .NET, would that still work? I am guessing it won't. Any similar alternative for my case? Thanks.

Comment: Probably won't work, but I re-wrote it for a Python framework :)

Comment: You're correct, probably not! I can't think of an off-the-shelf solution for you but I used it's logic and API calls to re-write it into Python.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does .net or rails mean to jQuery?  A jQuery plugin is independent on a server back end since jQuery is client side, unless you need to call into some back-end.